# ipcluster3.exe failed to create process

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython, anaconda

I am trying to run ipcluster3.exe on an Anaconda python 3.3 installation on Windows 7 64-bit.

However, when I run it I get an error:

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\Scripts>ipcluster3.exe
failed to create process.

C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\Scripts>ipcluster3.exe start -n 4
failed to create process.
```

The error doesn't really give me enough to start debugging.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like my copy of Anacondas came with a Beta version of IPython.

I updated it using Conda.

```
conda update -n py33 ipython


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ipython-2.3.1              |           py33_0         3.0 MB
    pyreadline-2.0             |           py33_0         135 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         3.1 MB

The following packages will be UN-linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ipython-0.13.2             |           py33_0
    pyreadline-2.0.dev         |           py33_0

The following packages will be linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ipython-2.3.1              |           py33_0   hard-link
    pyreadline-2.0             |           py33_0   hard-link
```